# Does lambdas execute operations in sequence.?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

We are contemplating using Amazon web services for our project. Wherein the upstream flow will push the messages into the kinesis and later those messages will be fed into the lambdas, those messages before processing are going to be in order. As per my understanding, the AWS lambdas will scale out horizontally based on the volume of the messages.  We have a volume of 400 messages per second, which means AWS lambda will respond to message volume and will instantiate new processes on separate containers to leverage parallelism and in order to achieve parallelism, ordering has to be compromised. So in case of 10 messages, which were ordered, hit the lambda functions and one function takes more time than another, a new function will be provisioned in some container by the AWS to serve the request.

Is the final output going to be in order after all of this processes?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the final output?  Dynamodb, rds, etc

Comment: The final output would be stored on SQS

Comment: Lambda doesn't guarantee FIFO for function execution in response to events and it certainly doesn't guarantee that Lambda N's write to SQS will precede Lambda (N+1)'s write to SQS. To say nothing of the potential impact of Lambda retries.

Comment: Hi jarmod,what i understood from your point is that lambda doesn't guarantee the sequence of function execution and the result of nth function execution doesn't necessarily precede N+1th  function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Amazon Kinesis, then you can use a [Data Transformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html) to trigger an AWS Lambda function on each incoming record.

This allows the record to be transformed or deleted, before continuing through the Firehose. Thus, records can be processed by Lambda while remaining in the same order. The final data can be delivered to Amazon S3, Amazon Redshift, Amazon Elasticsearch Service or Splunk.

If your application is consuming records from Amazon Kinesis directly (instead of via Firehose), then records will be consumed in order by your application.

Comment: in short: case1:when kinesis firehose used as the tool for streaming and transformation,it batches the records and call asyncronous labmda function on those records,and post processing continue with forwarding the data to the destination. does this asyncronous processing not distrub the order of the messages.                     CASE2: when Kinesis STREAMS used as the source- in this case since the order of messages are only maintained per shard and on subscription with lambda functions to read batch of records, are the records processed Asynchronously.if yes,don't we do away with ordering ?

Comment: You are correct that Kinesis Streams record ordering is preserved per-stream. This is why the producer should send a **partition key** to keep related records in order. If you require _all_ your records to be in order, then you could only use one stream, which would impact available throughput. Hopefully you can find a way to process records in parallel otherwise your processing would likely fall behind the speed of incoming records.

Comment: Thanks John,but my question was around the lambda execution,i want to know if the batch of records processed by Lambdas are returned in the order received or asynchronously,and later ordered- by partition key by firehose itself to send to the destination.

Comment: Hey @Sal were u able to find a solution to this.
We are right now facing a similar situation in which our messages needs to be processed in order. The use case is the `change` packet might reach first and then `process` packet. But at execution there is no guarantee that `process`  will do first . Hence we end up in stale result.
Any insights will be helpful.